# Django media image not found when there is a trailing slash at the end

Tags: javascript, django, url, python-imaging-library, media

I added users avatar today and applied it for my current 15 users or so when i was migrating, i just found out that the path wan't specified correctly so I had a look at my admin page to see what went wrong.
The wrong avatar url which all users currently have:  [...DefUser.png/](https://www.orgachat.com/media/users/img/avatar/DefUser.png/)
The correct one:  [...DefUser.png](https://www.orgachat.com/media/users/img/avatar/DefUser.png)

With the trailing slash it gives error, without gives the correct image. Is there anyway to fix that?! If not then How can i change the avatar image of all the current existing -15- users and make them all point to the same image?

---

The code

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='users/img/avatar/', default="users/img/avatar/DefUser.png/")
```

settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
LOGIN_URL = '/signup/'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path, include
...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

For existing users, change the value in the database (using admin panel, for example).

For new users, change `users/img/avatar/DefUser.png/` to `users/img/avatar/DefUser.png`?

Comment: I can't, in the admin page, all that i can do is upload a new image. As I said in the question I want all users to point to an existing image instead of uploading the same image 15 times which would consume almost 50% of the space. And what about new users? there was a user who signed up today and he have the same problem. Thanks for helping!